# InsertCommand.Parameters.Add size parameter for datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, ado.net, sqlparameter

I need to know what the size parameter should be for a DateTime value using the following syntax:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@deliveryDateAndTime", SqlDbType.DateTime,10,"deliveryDateAndTime");
```

I **cannot** use the following syntax because I'm batching the updates in a datatable.

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@deliveryDateAndTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@deliveryDateAndTime"] = *variable*.value;
```

Below is the code I need to use (abbreviated for clarity). Note that inside the `adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@deliveryDateAndTime", SqlDbType.DateTime,10,"deliveryDateAndTime");` statement, the **first** parameter refers to a corresponding SQL parameter and the **4th** parameter corresponds to the **data for that value inside the datatable.**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (FuelDelivery fd in fuelDelivery.FuelDeliveries)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["deliveryDateAndTime"] = fd.DeliveryDateAndTime;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HHSqlConnection"].ToString()))
{
    // Create a SqlDataAdapter.
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    // Set the INSERT command and parameter.
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@deliveryDateAndTime", SqlDbType.DateTime,10,"deliveryDateAndTime");
    adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

    // Set the batch size. Zero represents the maximum amt of rows to update at once.
    adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0;

    // Execute the update.
    int rowsUpdated = adapter.Update(dt);
}
```

Based on this overload for the `adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add` method, **how can I set the date accordingly?**

Comment: Please put more effort into fixing the indentation for code that you post - it's *horrible* at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) is 8 bytes according to the easily searchable documentation.

Note that you could also use your preferred overload and set the source column separately:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@deliveryDateAndTime", SqlDbType.DateTime)
                                .SourceColumn = "deliveryDateAndTime";
```